# Actualizar dos tablas no relacionadas con PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tablas, relaciones, actualizacion

Tengo dos tablas A y B que no están relacionadas en PostgreSQL y me gustaría realizar una actualiazación de las dos. Revisando las tablas tienen un campo id semejante, ¿existe la forma de realizar está tarea sin neceidad de relacionarlas?, ¿cuál sería el proceso,para realizarlo?

Agradeciendo sus comentarios.

Comment: No puedes hacer algo como lo que piensas si no estás seguro de que están relacionadas por ese id, de lo contrario arruinaría todo el proceso lógico de lo que sea que estés haciendo. Asegúrate de que ese campo sea el que los está relacionando y actualiza los campos para luego hacer tus update respectivos.

Comment: Ya mire el diagrama E-R y no se encuentran relacionadas. ¿Existe un query que pueda utilizar, para actualizar dos tablas no relacionadas en PostgreSQL?

Comment: En todo casa actualiza primero una y luego otra.